# How to plot a regression curve of Random Forest Model

Tags: python, matplotlib, random-forest

I am currently working on a project for which I have simulated/mock-up data. This data consists of multiple features of which only one is affecting the response variable. This is a very simplified use case because it is only for demo purposes.
I have used a basic random forest regression (scikit-learn) to predict the dependent variable. This model is performing rather well which was expected due to its simplicity. The thing I am having problems with is plotting a regression curve of the model (Remaining Useful Life is the dependent variable and temp is the feature which is affecting it). I am using pyplot to do this but I am not getting the expected result (see below). I would have expected the plot to be roughly the bottom curve. I am not sure why the straight lines above are there.

[image: Plot that is created]

To clarify what I was expecting to get:
Below is a scatter plot of the same data

[image: scatter plot of the data]

My questions regarding this:

1. Why is the plot coming out like this? Does it have something to do with how RF works?
2. Is there a way of getting a "clean" regression curve? (e.g. the shape of the scatter plot but one line) If so: how can this be achieved?

Code I am using for the plot:

```
plt.plot(y_hat_train_rf, X_train[['temp']], color='k')
```

Comment: `plt.plot()` plots a line from one point to the next, so it looks like that because your datapoints aren't sorted by X values.

Comment: Thanks! That should have been obvious to me. I have solved the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to F. Gyllenhammar's comment I have found a solution now. This should be obvious to experienced people but I will share my solution nevertheless.

Steps to solve:

1. Create new Dataframe that joins x and y.
2. sort by x
3. plot

Comment: you should write the code.